# ajax / codeigniter out put create a new row every 4 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

In the success part of my ajax each result gets put into columns.

What I am trying to achive is every 4 columns it will create a new row.

Question: On success part of ajax how to make it so every after every 4 columns will create a new row?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#select_category").on('keyup', function(e) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('questions/displaycategories');?>", 
        data: {
            category: $("#select_category").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(json){
            list = '';

            list += '<div class="row">';

            $.each(json['categories'], function(key, value ) {
                list += '<div class="col-sm-3">';

                list += value['name'];

                list += '</div>';   
            });

            list += '</div>';

            $('.category-box').html(list);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just count how many you've added and insert a new row each time it reaches 4:

```
$("#select_category").on('keyup', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('questions/displaycategories');?>",
    data: {
      category: $("#select_category").val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
      var list = '<div class="row">';
      var index = 0;

      $.each(json['categories'], function(key, value) {
        list += '<div class="col-sm-3">';
        list += value['name'];
        list += '</div>';
        index++;
        if(index === 4) {
          list += '</div><div class="row">';
          index = 0;
        }
      });

      list += '</div>';

      $('.category-box').html(list);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
success: function(json){
    list = '';
    var cnt = 0;
    list += '<div class="row">';
    $.each(json['categories'], function(key, value ) {
        list += '<div class="col-sm-3">';
        list += value['name'];
        list += '</div>';
        cnt++;

        if(!cnt%4){
            list += '</div><div class="row">';
            cnt = 0;
        }
    });
    list += '</div>';
    $('.category-box').html(list);
}
```